# or statement in list python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-3.4

I am in the process of making a tic tac toe program for my python 3 class and was wondering why my computer win move isn't working correctly. It seems that the 'or' in 'list' function is not being evaluated correctly. Is there another way to accomplish the evaluation conditions?

```
def winningMoves():
    print('starting computer winning move')
    i = [1, 2, 3, 7]
    if (1 and 2 in i) or (5 and 7 in i) or (6 and 9 in i):
        drawBoardlist[3] = computerCharacter
    elif (2 and 3 in i) or (4 and 7 in i) or (5 and 9 in i):
        drawBoardlist[1] = computerCharacter
    elif (1 and 2 in i) or (3 and 5 in i) or (8 and 9 in i):
        drawBoardlist[7] = computerCharacter
    elif (7 and 8 in i) or (1 and 5 in i) or (3 and 6 in i):
        drawBoardlist[10] = computerCharacter
    else:
        print('No winning moves')
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(1 and 2 in i)` is parsed as `((1) and (2 in i))`. Instead you probably meant

```
((1 in i) and (2 in i))
```

and similarly for all the other conditions.

---

Compare for example,

```
In [47]: i = [1, 2, 3, 7]

In [48]: (100 and 2 in i)
Out[48]: True

In [49]: ((100 in i) and (2 in i))
Out[49]: False
```

---

The [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) shows `and` has a lower precedence than `in`. Therefore `in` binds more tightly than `and` and so `in` binds to `(2 in i)` before the `and` binds `1` and `(2 in i)` to form `1 and (2 in i)`.

This is why `(1 and 2 in i)` is parsed as `((1) and (2 in i))`.

---

By the way, checking if an item is in a list is an O(n) operation. If you are doing this a lot, as it seems you are, you will be better off making the list into a set first since checking for membership in a set is O(1).

```
iset = set(i)
if (1 in iset and 2 in iset)
```

or

```
if iset.issuperset((1, 2))
```